# The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large Error In Wcf Service

Tags: c#, wcf

In the below code i am working on wcf service i upload a text file or pdf file it is uploading when i try to upload image file it throws error "The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large.".Pls anyone help me to solve the issue.

File.aspx.cs

```
 public void FileUpload(string FilePath, string FolderName)
        {



                FileServiceClient fileTranz = new FileServiceClient();

                var fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
                FileInfo info = new FileInfo(FilePath);
                string filename = info.Name.ToString();

                var fileDto = new FileDto
                {
                    FileName = filename,
                    FileSize = fileContent.Length,
                    Content = fileContent
                };



                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
                var response = fileTranz.ServicetaxFileUpload(fileDto, fileName, "Image", sFileTransKey, FolderName);
                if ((System.IO.File.Exists(FilePath)))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(FilePath);
                }                         



        }
```

FileService.svc.cs

```
public bool ServicetaxFileUpload(FileDto fileDto, string sFileName, string sFileType, string sCallFrom, string FolderName)
        {
                if (sCallFrom != "ttdll")
                    return false;
var Uploadpath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HoardServer"].ToString();
                    Uploadpath = Uploadpath.TrimEnd("\\".ToCharArray()) + "\\PaidESI\\" + sFileName;
                    var DirectoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(Uploadpath);
                    DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(DirectoryName);
                    if (!dInfo.Exists)
                    {
                        dInfo.Create();
                    }

                    if (sFileType == "Image")
                    {
                        //if (!File.Exists(Uploadpath))
                        File.WriteAllBytes(Uploadpath , fileDto.Content);
                    }
                    else if (sFileType == "Xml")
                        File.WriteAllBytes(Uploadpath , fileDto.Content);
                    else
                        File.WriteAllBytes(Uploadpath , fileDto.Content);
                }
```

Webconfig

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
          messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
```

Comment: And how "Large" is your image?

Comment: @Edi G More than 800KB